# Google Apps Script -- new Date() should return today's date (4/6/2020) but instead gives 3/1/2020

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
        function test(){
 date = new Date();
     dd = date.getDay();
     mm = date.getMonth();
     yyyy = date.getFullYear();
     Logger.log(mm,dd,yyyy);

}
```

Any ideas why this is logging the wrong date? I'm baffled.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Is it running on the server? The server should be with the wrong date.

Comment: Yes - that does answer it.... and the worst part is I've looked this up before and knew that this is how it was done. *dons dunce cap*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test(){
 const date = new Date();
 const dd=date.getDate();
 const mm = date.getMonth()+1;
 const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
 Logger.log(mm,dd,yyyy);

}
```

[Javascript Date() object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Thanks! That did it.